# Having difficulty with a custom newcommand

Tags: macros

I am trying to convert the following into code into a custom new command which takes three arguments: quote, author, profession. Manually the code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, shadows}

\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\trfamily{JennaSue.ttf}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}

\trfamily
\begin{flushright}
\begin{LARGE}
\reflectbox{"}It is the unknown that excites the ardor of scholars, who,\\ in the known alone, would shrivel up with boredom."
\end{LARGE}
\end{flushright}
\rmfamily

\begin{flushright}
\begin{footnotesize}
\textit{\textsc{ - Wallace Stevens}}\\
\textit{American Poet}
\end{footnotesize}
\end{flushright}
\vspace{2cm}

\end{document}
```

the output is:

[image]

What I have tried:

```
\newcommand\quotation[3]{\trfamily\begin{flushright}\begin{LARGE}\reflectbox{"}{#1}\end{LARGE}\end{flushright}\rmfamily\begin{footnotesize}\textit{\textsc{ - {#2}}}\\\textit{{#3}}\end{footnotesize}\end{flushright}\vspace{2cm}}
```

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: @samcarter give me a sec...

Comment: Another comment: `LARGE`, `flushright`, `footnotesize` aren't really environments, so you should not use them as such. (It may create undesirable side effects, such as spurious spaces.) Instead, use `\LARGE` `\flushright`, `\footnotesize`. Example: `{\footnotesize some text in footnote size}`. Note the use of braces to localise the effect of the `\footnotesize` declaration.

Comment: The `\reflectbox{"}` looks ugly.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I know - unfortunately the ttf I'm using for some reason doesn't support the 66 version of " but only 99 of the ", therefore the quotes appear as 99some quote99 which doesn't look too appealing to the eye....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As Harald Hanche-Olsen also suggested in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446799/having-difficulty-with-a-custom-newcommand/446801#comment1122361_446799) font size commands like `\LARGE` are switches and don't take arguments.
- then `\begin{flushright}` is missing
- wrapping `#1` etc. in `{}` is not necessary
- closing quotation marks are missing

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, shadows}

\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\trfamily{JennaSue.ttf}

\newcommand{\quatation}[3]{%
\trfamily
\begin{flushright}
\LARGE \reflectbox{"}~#1''
\end{flushright}
\rmfamily

\begin{flushright}
\footnotesize
\textit{\textsc{ - #2}}\\
\textit{#3}
\end{flushright}
\vspace{2cm}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}

\quatation{It is the unknown that excites the ardor of scholars, who,\\ in the known alone, would shrivel up with boredom.}{Wallace Stevens}{American Poet}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily obtain a command using the `epigraph` package: I defined a `\myepigraph` command, which is but `\epigraph` with custom  parameters. I also added a thin space in your `\reflectbox`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, shadows}

\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\trfamily{JennaSue.ttf}

\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.8\linewidth}
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
%\renewcommand{\textflush}{\raggedleft}

\newcommand{\myepigraph}[2]{%
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.8\linewidth}
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
\setlength{\afterepigraphskip}{35pt}
\epigraph{\raggedleft\trfamily{\LARGE #1}\medskip}{\footnotesize\itshape #2}
}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\myepigraph{\reflectbox{\,"}It is the unknown that excites the ardor of scholars, who,\\ in the known alone, would shrivel up with boredom."}{\textsc{– Wallace Stevens}\\American Poet}

\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]